# React Native FlatList numColumn does not render items inline

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Here is my issue, my flatlist has the following attributes:

```
<FlatList
  horizontal={false}
  numColumns={4}
  ...
```

But the items are not being rendered correctly, here is an image

[image]

Comment: Why do you have horizontal false?

Comment: @harshitraghav because it use `numColumns` only be [rendered](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#numcolumns) with `horizontal={false}`

Comment: Well, I recently used it without having horizontal set to false. I think you should debug your screen width, if it has any margin or anything else it could be because of image width as well.

Comment: Or maybe is the layout style caused at the parent container style? If you post more information about styles should be better to know.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be very careful with the `borderWidth` of your elements. Please set them to 0. Even if your elements `width` is `(deviceWidth/4)`, the screen will not fill with 4 elements if they have a borderWidth > 0 because it will push them to the next row.